# Waveshare GSM HAT and RPi camera

Tags: pi-3b+

Does anyone know, if the waveshare gsm hat affects the camera unit on the raspberry pi? Because if I plug the hat on the RPi, then I can't use the camera.

Comment: It is likely that WaveShare GSM crashes with Rpi camera. Can you tell us the gsm hat model, so that we can see if the GSM module driver crashes with other devices.  Perhaps you can tell us which GSM module you are using.  Sometimes old drivers does not work with new version of Rapsbian.

Comment: "The GSM HAT only use UART pins, Vcc, GND and P4. You can use GPIOs except these three pins." This is from waveshare, when I asked about which GPIO's I can use. Does the UART has something to do with the camera module?

Comment: I checked the Rpi Camera hardware interface and found that it only uses 2 I2C #0 pins, so should not crash with GSM HAT's UART and P4 (pls confirm if you mean GPIO4, the GCLK pin).  I know very little of the Rpi Camera driver software.  It is likely that the driver sets GCLK frequency, and if GSM HAT driver also set GCLK frequency, then we are in trouble.  But I am only guessing, because I don't know the details of both GSM driver and Camera driver. :(